# Using Qt5 to create apps for iOS and Android

Tags: android, c++, ios, qt, qt5

As an intermediate-level programmer of C++ (that have been working on C++ for console apps and used only [FLTK](http://www.fltk.org/index.php) for GUI apps), I heard much about Qt5 to be suitable and very powerful for creating apps for many platforms such as Windows, Linux, iOS and also Android.

I'm now a novice on Qt and to create apps for PC, I'm going to start reading [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132354160) book (which is of Qt4).
But I, too, like to start reading a good book on Qt5 that makes me able to create apps for iOS and Android. Is there such a good book?

Any suggestion is fully appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This book will give you common sense about Qt, but keep in mind that there's a lot of difference between Qt4 and Qt5 (most important that Qt5 improves QtQuick module). To build your iOS or Android app I suggest you will need look deep inside of QtQuick. This [book](http://qmlbook.github.io/) will help you a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had to read that Qt4 book because there isn't any complete reference on Qt5 yet. :(